# want download only last line of a file in url using C#

Tags: c#

want download only  last line of a file in URL  using C#

Is it possible or should I always download whole file for that last line.

when I request a URL it gives a text that will update every 5 minute.

Can I download only last Line from that url?

Comment: Do you have control of the resource provider? Can you set it up to only return a file with the updates from the last few minutes? Or to receive and respond to parameterised requests?

If not, I suspect you'll have to download the file in full. Is the file size significant?

Comment: It depends on your stream, if you can seek on stream, then can jump to specific place and read from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for you to achieve what you're asking, you would need to know the exact byte range of the last line in the file... which is something that is unlikely for you to know ahead of time.

The server you're making the request to will also need to support the functionality. You can find out whether it does or not by looking at the headers of the response it will include this header `Accept-Ranges: bytes`

Here's how to make a partial content request...

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.AddRange(0, 599);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())    
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Console.WriteLine ("Stream size in bytes: {0}", memoryStream.Length);

    while (memoryStream.Position != memoryStream.Length)
    {
        Console.Write (Convert.ToChar(memoryStream.ReadByte()));
    }
}
```